# Can any jquery or html5 plugin/script play local video files?

Tags: jquery, video, html5-video, local

I want to create a demo page, that plays a local video file on my hard drive.

The demo page's url will be file:/// based as well.

The video files are almost all avi.

I have tried jquery media plugin, and jplayer, and have had no luck playing any videos locally.

Comment: Html is a browser how can it play a local file you first have to upload it to server then html 5 can do the magic.....

Comment: html is a language for translating the data sent/received via http. If i put the file:/// of the movie as the url, it will play, I just want to play it within the web page.

Comment: Is there any way to make this happen? Any method?

Comment: yeah place the video file in the relative path as with the html page.....and then using the respective tags you can achieve these

Comment: I was using chrome to create a web player. for local uploading i had to change the target of my chrome shortcut(on my desktop) to include --allow-file-access-from-files after the quotes. this allowed me to upload local files

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to play local videos if you give a relative path to the video, that is, put the video in the same place (or a subdirectory of) where the HTML file is and point the player to that file. So instead of `file:///path/to/movie.avi` use `media/movie.avi` (where `media` is a subdirectory of the directory where the HTML file is).

Note that some browsers have extra security measures in place when running local HTML/JavaScript, so especially in IE you might need to tweak the security the settings first.

Comment: But the web folder is in a different folder path then the movie folder.